# AVSpeechUtterance and appstore = app rejected

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, voice

sadly i got my app rejected because of siri voice
"Apps that relate to Siri are not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines as Siri is an Apple product, and therefore covered by our Trademarks and Copyrights guidelines."

there was no information to not using siri voice in appstore app,so i dont get why this function is published.
Anyway im looking for easy to use example which is ok  using to appstore.

```
-(void)readTextWithSiri:(NSString*)text{
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *syn = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer aloc] init];
    utterance.rate = 0.032;
    [syn speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```

Comment: I think they mean you used or talked about siri on your app description or some other place

Comment: There is no information about using siri voice. ive only used this function.
Tell me if using [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-au"]; is okay with appstore?

Comment: Maybe the problem is the name of the funcion, readTextWithSiri

Comment: That would only be an issue if you shipped the code with labels intact. Apple likely scans the binary for strings that match its trademarks and other text. Always ship apps without labels. Use something like Crashlytics to symbolicate a crash report instead.